# UTF-8 strings were wrongly decoded as UTF-16 in excel. How can I encode and decode the file so special characters display correctly?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I've received a .xlsx file where foreign language characters appear to have to have been originally encoded as utf-8 and then decoded as utf-16.

I don't have access to the original file.

Ã© and Ã³, for example, should be read as é and ó, respectively, which are encoded as 0xC3 0xA9 and 0xC3 0xB3. Instead each single utf-8 character has been decoded at some point as two utf-16 characters.

I've tried encoding them to bytes and decoding them with UTF-8, but that doesn't translate correctly.

This:

```
    s = "Ã³".encode("utf-16")
    uni = s.decode("utf-8")
    print(uni)
```

returns this:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

I've tried the above encode/decode sequence with a variety of different parameters including UTF-16be and UTF-16le, and every error parameter of decode, and just slicing off the BOM, none of which worked.

Is there a way to fix this? Some library that can make this a less painful process than doing a literal replacement by reading every string and replacing Ã³ with ó?

Comment: `"Ã³".encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` or more likely on Windows `"Ã³".encode('windows-1252').decode('utf8')`

Comment: Always check your assumptions before trying to debug things. In this case: Excel used cp1252 or Latin-1 but not UTF-16 (and it was "foreign" it may used other encoding). Do not use "foreign" for non ASCII characters: good English requires more then 256 characters (so also "Windows ANSI" is way to small).